# Change Text base on the Active Image on Swiper Slider

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am going to change the H2 value base on the active image of the swiper slider and swiper plugins already imported. I have two state which is the title, setTitle and description, setDescription.
but when rendered the h2 value is not populated by the Title and the description also.

**Code Started**

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const Images = [
    {
      id: 1,
      images:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509721434272-b79147e0e708?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      images:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506710507565-203b9f24669b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1536&q=80",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      images:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536987333706-fc9adfb10d91?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80",
    },
  ];
  const Text = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Sunset",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, non commodi.",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Sunrise",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, non commodi.",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Moon Light",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, non commodi.",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="h-[100vh] flex justify-center items-center">
      <Swiper
        onSlideChange={() =>
          setTitle(Text.title),
          setDescription(Text.description)
        }
        onSwiper={(swiper) =>
          console.log(swiper)
        }
        className="justify-center items-center max-w-[1440px]"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509721434272-b79147e0e708?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509721434272-b79147e0e708?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509721434272-b79147e0e708?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80" />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <div className="flex flex-row md:flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <h2 className="text-5xl text-white font-cerabold">
          {title}
        </h2>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using the onSlideChange and getting the realIndex from the image, then using it on a state to search trough an array.

here is the example:

```
const Slider = ({ isDesktop }) => {

const [activeImageIndex, setActiveImageIndex] = React.useState(1)

const texts = [
    {
      name: 'user1',
      crp: 'CRP: **********',
      role: 'coodinator'
    },
    {
      name: 'user2',
      crp: 'CRP: *******',
      role: 'teacher'
    },
    {
      name: 'user3',
      crp: 'CRP: ****',
      role: 'admin'
    },
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <Swiper
        direction='vertical'
        autoplay={{
          delay: 3500
        }}
        slidesPerView={1}
        allowTouchMove={false}
        spaceBetween={700}
        onSlideChange={(swiper) =>
           setActiveImageIndex(swiper.realIndex)
        }
        loop
        style={{
          height: isDesktop ? '600px' : '330px',
          width: isDesktop ? '600px' : '330px',
          backgroundSize: isDesktop ? '600px' : '330px',
          backgroundImage: `url(${sliderBackground})`,
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
        }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <SlideContainer>
            <ImageMask isDesktop={isDesktop}>
              <img
                src={require('../public/image1.png')}
                width={isDesktop ? 400 : 240}
              />
            </ImageMask>
          </SlideContainer>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <SlideContainer>
            <ImageMask isDesktop={isDesktop}>
              <img
                src={require('../public/image2.png')}
                width={isDesktop ? 400 : 240}
              />
            </ImageMask>
          </SlideContainer>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <SlideContainer>
            <ImageMask isDesktop={isDesktop}>
              <img
                src={require('../public/image3.png')}
                width={isDesktop ? 400 : 240}
              />
            </ImageMask>
          </SlideContainer>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <BottomMask />
      <DataContainer>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 4, marginTop: 4 }}>
          {texts[activeImageIndex].name}
          <br />
          <span>
            {texts[activeImageIndex].crp}
          </span>
        </div>
        <span>
          {texts[activeImageIndex].role}
        </span>
      </DataContainer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The Swiper prop does not update the states.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem and wrote this code to make this happen. You just need to set the state of the active slide index and use it like I added the if-else on slides.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import {Autoplay} from "swiper";

const BASE_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;

export const Slider = (props) => {

const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(1);

return (
    <Swiper
        slidesPerView={3}
        spaceBetween={1}
        loop={true}
        modules={[Autoplay]}
        roundLengths={true}
        centeredSlides={true}
        autoplay={{
            delay: 3000,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        breakpoints={{
            200: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10,
            },
            640: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                spaceBetween: 20,
            }
        }}
        onSlideChange={swiper => setActiveSlide(swiper.realIndex)}
    >
        {
            [...Array(3)].map((_, index) => {
                if (index === activeSlide) {
                    return <SwiperSlide key={index} style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <img src={`${BASE_URL}/images/slider-images/${index}.png`}
                             style={{width: '325px', height: '380px'}} alt=""/>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                } else {
                    return <SwiperSlide key={index} style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <img src={`${BASE_URL}/images/slider-images/${index}-shadow.png`}
                             style={{width: '260px', height: '300px'}} alt=""/>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                }
            })
        }
    </Swiper>
);
};
```